# UML (or similar) for JSF/xhtml

Tags: jsf, xhtml, uml, project, flowchart

Sort of a new area for me, but the project I'm working on involves a lot of `.xhtml` files that include JSF and Javascript (lots of `<ui:include>`s). I'm hoping to find an eclipse plugin or other piece of software that will allow me to view and navigate through these files in a flowchart/UML-like diagram.

Searches have turned up lots of plugins,  but it isn't very clear if they'll do what I'm looking for. So far the ones I've tried have not. Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your files in UML using standard UML deployment elements and diagrams. You can define files as artifacts with specific file extension and use deployment relationship to depict to which nodes are your files deployed. Nodes could be executable environments like web server, object container etc. You can create informative network with precise navigation this way. If you also need to define structure of XML or HTML tags, try to find special UML Profile rather than plugin. (for example UML profile for XML, UML Profile for HTML etc.)